# Ubuntu 18.04 unable to use apt / dpkg, numerous configuration issues

Tags: boot, apt, dpkg, python3

Unable to install anything using apt / pkg.  Whenever I try to install something, I get a list of errors around python3 and other packages not being configured.  When I run `dpkg --configure -a` I get `Processing was halted because there were too many errors` along with a list of packages mostly `python3` related but also many system-related packages (`gnome-session, gdm3, udev)`. Removing / reinstalling errors out because of of dependency / configuration errors, I suspect because `apt` and `python3` issues.  Unable to boot my machine currently but able to get to TTY2.

Comment: For us to provide meaningful help; you need to provide the messages so we can see your issue. From what you provided, it reads like a user with `sudo` rights on your system has made changes to the default python/python3 versions, thus the tools that require python/python3 to be the *default* version no longer function correctly; but that's a guess as you've provided no specific messages to allow exploration of causes.

Comment: How would I set the default version of python3 used by apt?  Unable to paste errors because my linux box won't boot (only able to drop to tty2) so am typing this from another computer.  In `usr/bin` I have multiple versions of python.